# Adding sleuth to project breaks @ConfigurationProperties class

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have some strange issue after adding:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

to my pom.xml. It breaks a class which uses `@ConfigurationProperties`. Exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Could not bind properties to LoginController (prefix=myPrefix, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.rebind(ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.java:100)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.rebind(ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.java:88)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.onApplicationEvent(ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.onApplicationEvent(ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.java:1)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335)
    at org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.afterSingletonsInstantiated(ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.java:79)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:792)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.company.myproject.Application.main(Application.java:13)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.extendCollectionIfNecessary(RelaxedDataBinder.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.initializePath(RelaxedDataBinder.java:291)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.normalizePath(RelaxedDataBinder.java:259)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperty(RelaxedDataBinder.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperties(RelaxedDataBinder.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:128)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:715)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:269)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:241)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:334)
    ... 26 more
```

I inject a list of instances using yml:

```
myPrefix.locales:
    -
      code: "en"
      language: "English"
    -
      code: "sv"
      language: "Svenska"

@Data
@Component
public class Locale {
    private String code;
    private String language;
}
```

and this list is injected despite of error ( I log list values it in `@PostConstruct` method ), but then it fails with above exception.

spring boot version: 1.3.5.RELEASE

it works fine without sleuth.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you've also asked this in Sleuth's repo - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/288